# A/B testing is showing a change of 42% in Top Goal Converted. How Sitecore calculate this change value?

Tags: content-testing

I implemented `A/B testing` in `Sitecore 10.1.2`. Now we are getting a result of `Top Goal Converter`. Now I am not able to understand how this Change value 42% is calculated, please check the image below. The goal it is referring, is new and created for this test only.
I checked below URL form Sitecore and from there it means `the change between the original experience and the selected experience`.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/101/sitecore-experience-platform/content-test-results.html

[image]

Can anyone please help me to understand how Sitecore is calculating the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run an A/B – or multivariate test, Sitecore will assess its success based on the `trailing value/visit`, which is the average collected `engagement value` after being exposed to the test. The logic behind this is: If there is a significant engagement value difference between the variations of your content, it can be attributed to the content the visitors see.

The `engagement value` is an integer that aggregates for each contact over time. The most common way of increasing the engagement value is to create a goal in Sitecore and assign it to an action, like visiting a certain page or submitting a form. The engagement value of a contact tells you how valuable this contact is for your organization, while the `value per visit (= average change in engagement value per website visit)` tells you how successful your website is in achieving your business goals.

So in your case, it measures the `First Page Submission` goal is a top converted goal during the test period and it got highrer converstion and engegement value then other goals.

Take a look [this](https://sitecore.merkle.com/the-engagement-value/) for better understanding.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, Sumit, for the valuable input.

Answer (score 2):

Sumit's answer perfectly explains how the `Engagement Value` and `Trailing value/visit` numbers are calculated.

When it comes to `Goals`, `Conversion rate` and `Change` columns that are shown on the screenshot, these are calculated differently.

[image: Example of the Top Goals converted table]

First of all, `Conversions` is the number of times each goal was triggered for visitors who were exposed to this A/B test. `Conversion rate` is percentage of visits with goal conversions out of total visits (i.e. the number of goal conversions after viewing the selected experience divided by the number of visits).

Then, for the `Change` column Sitecore compares conversion rate that is calculated separately for Original and Variant experiences of the A/B test:

```
Change = (VariantCoversionRate - OriginalConversionRate)/OriginalConversionRate
```

where `VariantCoversionRate = VariantConversions/VariantVisits` and `OriginalConversionRate = OriginalConversions/OriginalVisits` for the same goal.

So the `Change` column shows the difference in conversion rate between different variants rather than change in the absolute number of conversions or total engagement value.